# VBA powerpoint: Size and align 2 images on one slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to get two pictures to resize and align side by side...think like a before and after comparison on one slide.  The pictures are already imported to the slide.  I have two macros written, one for the left one for the right, based on the selected shape but was looking to combine to one.

Here is what I have (rookie) to combine

```
'Updated Macro 
Sub SidebySide()
Dim oSp As Shape
Dim oSld As Slide

If CheckIsPic(oSp) = True Then
With oSp
    Do
        .Height = (5.6 * 72)
        .Width = (4.8 * 72)
        .Left = (0.2 * 72)
        .Top = (1.3 * 72)
    Loop While oSp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
End With

With oSp
    Do
            .Height = (5.6 * 72)
            .Width = (4.8 * 72)
            .Left = (5# * 72)
            .Top = (1.3 * 72)
    Loop While oSp <> ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
End With

End If

End Sub

Function CheckIsPic(oSp As Shape) As Boolean
If oSp.Type = msoPicture Then CheckIsPic = True
End If
End Function
```

It is not running so I know I probably have something wrong in there, but essentially I am trying to run a loop if it is a pic on the slide...do A to the selection, do B to the non selection.

Any ideas?  I am sure there is a much better way to go about this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that moving the `With` OUTSIDE the `Do...Loop` will solve the issue. (do it twice)

```
With oSp
    Do
        .Height = (5.6 * 72)
        .Width = (4.8 * 72)
        .Left = (0.2 * 72)
        .Top = (1.3 * 72)
    Loop While oSp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
End With
```

Comment: Hmm.  Now it is not running the CheckIsPic saying module not defined

Comment: Well, he's probably right :-) Click on CheckIsPic and press Shift+F2 to verify. If the function exists, it will bring you there.

Comment: OK added a function at in my editted original post....No bugs but nothing seems to be changing

Comment: If the picture is in a placeholder, then .Type will not be msoPicture but msoPlaceholder, in which case you need to check the .PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType (if memory serves) to see if IT is msoPicture.

Comment: CheckIsPic: if you write something after `Then`,  then the `End If` should be removed